# how to alter and then show attributes in html with php

Tags: php, html, dom

in my table, I have a row that contains a string like this:

```html
<p>hello</p><p>this is patrick</p><p><img src="/assets/img/myface.jpg" width="320" height="320"/></p>
```

and I want to give the `<img>` tag an `alt` attribute. I've got quite close now but somehow my code still shows 2 `<img>` tags although the string only has 1. can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

this is my code so far:

```php
$str = '<p>hello</p><p>this is patrick</p><p><img src="/assets/img/myface.jpg" width="320" height="320"/></p>';
$new_html = '';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($str);
$content = $dom->getElementsByTagName('*');
foreach ($content as $i => $node)
{
  if ($node->nodeName == 'html' || $node->nodeName == 'body')
  {
    continue; // dont need to process these tags, right?
  }

  if ($node->nodeName == 'img')
  {
    $img_src = $node->getAttribute('src');
    $path_arr = explode('/', $img_src);
    $filename = $path_arr[count($path_arr)-1]; // myface.jpg

    $alt = 'blah';
    $node->setAttribute('alt', $alt);
  }

  echo $dom->saveXML($node);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slightly changed code below does the work. It only gets the `img` tags and saves the HTML outside the loop. Note that I changed the way that HTML was loaded, to not include the wrapper tags.

```
<?php

$str = '<p>hello</p><p>this is patrick</p><p><img src="/assets/img/myface.jpg" width="320" height="320"/></p>';
$new_html = '';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($str, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$content = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($content as $i => $node)
{

  $img_src = $node->getAttribute('src');
  $path_arr = explode('/', $img_src);
  $filename = $path_arr[count($path_arr)-1]; // myface.jpg

  $alt = 'blah';
  $node->setAttribute('alt', $alt);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$content = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($content as $node) {
    $img_src = $node->getAttribute('src');
    $filename = basename($img_src);

    $node->setAttribute('alt', $filename);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Loop only through images with `$content = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');`

Move `$dom->saveHTML();` after lthe loop.

Get filename with `$filename = basename($img_src);`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you use

```
echo $dom->saveXML($node);
```

in the loop, it will output for various tags and so the output is not the end result, but a combination of other parts of the document.

Try changing it to

```
echo $node->nodeName."=>".$dom->saveXML($node).PHP_EOL;
```

to see what it does.

You could just remove the current `echo` and add

```
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

after the end of the loop.

Alternatively, if you just want to process the `<img>` tags, you can limit the loop more specifically...

```
$content = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($content as $i => $node)
{
    $img_src = $node->getAttribute('src');
    $path_arr = explode('/', $img_src);
    $filename = $path_arr[count($path_arr)-1]; // myface.jpg

    $alt = 'blah';
    $node->setAttribute('alt', $alt);
}
echo $dom->saveXML();
```